# javascript function returning day of week x num of days later

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary

What I am trying to write is a simple function that takes in a day (D), X number of days and returns the day X days later.

Days can be represented by ('Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu','Fri','Sat','Sun').

X can be any int 0 and up.

For Example D='Wed', X='2', return 'Fri', D='Sat' and X='5', returns 'Wed'.

How do I do this in JS? Any tips and suggestions appreciated.

Comment: If you have an array `const dayNames = ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun']`, the problem gets simpler: you only have to work with numbers from 0 to 6.

Comment: okay, but how to do the logic for returning the day x days later?

Comment: If you have the number 1, do you have any ideas on how to get the number 3 numbers after it?

Comment: D="Sat" and X="5" should be Thursday shouldn't it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, then perhaps you could do something like the following:

1. find the index of input "d" against days of the week
2. apply "x" to offset the found index
3. apply modulo operator by total number of days (7) to revolve offset index around valid day range
4. return resulting day by that computed index

Here's a code snippet - hope that helps!

```js
function getWeekDayFromOffset(d, x) {

  // Array of week days
  const days = ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu','Fri','Sat','Sun'];
  
  // Find index of input day "d"
  const dIndex = days.indexOf(d);
  
  // Take add "x" offset to index of "d", and apply modulo % to
  // revolve back through array
  const xIndex = (dIndex + x) % days.length;
  
  // Return the day for offset "xIndex"
  return days[xIndex];
}

console.log('returns Fri:', getWeekDayFromOffset('Wed', 2));
console.log('returns Thu:', getWeekDayFromOffset('Sat', 5));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# write a code to return week day after adding k number Week_name=("Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun")
#example ('Wed',2) then return Fri 
#example ('Sat',2) then 'Mon'
# here N is postive number from 1 to infinity 
#here S is valid week day name
def week_day(S,K):
    Week_name=("Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun")
    ind=Week_name.index(S)
    #trimming k value from 0 to 6
    K=K%7
    n=len(Week_name)
    print("ind is {0} S is {1} K {2}".format(ind,S,K))
    if ind+K<n:
        return Week_name[ind+K]
    else:
        return Week_name[ind+K-n]
print(week_day('Wed',2))
print(week_day('Sun',2))
print(week_day('Wed',500)) # here 500 converted into 3 as reminder 
print(week_day('Wed',0))
print(week_day('Sat',5))
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32068227)